# 'class': illegal use of this type as an expression how do I fix it?

Tags: c++, class

When trying to compile my program I get these errors

1>c:\users\danilo\desktop\lab2\project1\project1\main.cpp(11): error C2275: 'Fighter': illegal use of this type as an expression
1>c:\users\danilo\desktop\lab2\project1\project1\fighter.h(9): note: see declaration of 'Fighter'
1>c:\users\danilo\desktop\lab2\project1\project1\main.cpp(11): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'f1'
1>c:\users\danilo\desktop\lab2\project1\project1\main.cpp(12): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
1>c:\users\danilo\desktop\lab2\project1\project1\main.cpp(12): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '}'

My main file looks like this:

```
#include "Fighter.h"
#include "Spell.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include "Wizard.h"
#include "Collection.h"

int lastID = 0;

int main{
    Fighter f1;
    f1("A", 100, 100);
};
```

and my Fighter.h looks like this

```
#define FIGHTER_H

#include "Card.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Fighter : public Card {
    int power;
public:
    virtual string getCategory() const override {
        return "FIGHTER";
    }
    int getPower() const {
        return power;
    }
    Fighter(string Name_, int neededEnergy_, int power_) : Card(Name_, neededEnergy_), power(power_) {}
    void operator>(const Fighter& f) const {
        if (this->getPower() > f.getPower()) {
            cout << this->getName() << " is stronger " << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << f.getName() << " is stronger " << endl;
        };
    }
    virtual void write(ostream& it) const override {
        it << "(power: " << getPower() << ")";
    }
};


#endif FIGHTER_H
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: `Fighter f1("A", 100, 100);` - This is call to the constructor. `Fighter f1;
    f1("A", 100, 100);` This is call to `operator()()`

Comment: You are missing the brackets after `main` It must be `main() { ... }` not `main{ ... }`

Comment: You are missing #ifndef in Fighter.h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `main` function is missing its parentheses. This

```
int main{
```

should be

```
int main(){
```

Also, `f1("A", 100, 100)` isn't a constructor call, but a call to `operator()`, which you don't have. Do this instead:

```
Fighter f1("A", 100, 100);
```

Also, ensure that your guards are consistent. There's a `#ifndef FIGHTER_H` missing.

Comment: `#pragma once` in the `Fighter.h` file will be also welcome

Comment: @Raffallo `#pragma once` isn't standard, although most compilers support it. You're definitely right about that there's an issue with the include guards, though. There was a missing `#ifndef`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I do have the `#ifndef` just didn't copy it here.